My PHP cURL Proxy isn't working and/or loading images or other files
I've tried making many proxies with PHP but they all end up with either headers not loading properly or images not loading properly. I'm very new to PHP and I've looked up how to make one but for my proxy I want the url to be located at a url query called url ?url.
<?php
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
if (empty($url)) {
  http_response_code(400);
  die('Error: URL parameter is missing.');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
  http_response_code(500);
  die('Error: Failed to fetch URL - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if (strpos($contentType, 'image/') === 0) {
  header("Content-Type: $contentType");
  echo $response;
} else {
  $response = preg_replace_callback('/(src|href)=\"((?!http(s)?:\/\/)(?!\/\/)(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|svg))/i', function($matches) use ($url) {
    return $matches[1] . '="' . $url . $matches[2];
  }, $response);
  echo $response;
}
?>

It works to some extent but breaks many times, especially with images.
I want all images and headers to load properly and have each tag check for an src, then check if it is simply a /example.file or an https://example.com/example.file since what my code does is it trys to load the image/file on my server (I'm using Replit btw). https://server.com/example.file however that file does not exist. I've tried making the code add the website url to the begining of the /example.file of the ?url query but I'm not sure I'm using the best method. I'm a pure beginer with PHP as well so I may be doing several things wrong.
I've also noticed that for things such as https://google.com when searching it will redirecting to https://google.com/search?{things} and my proxy will do the same, but like said it will do it on the web server where there is no such thing as /search and send the user to https://server.com/search?{things} instead of https://server.com/?url=https://google.com/search?{things}.
EDIT:
I changed the code a little bit and it works better, but the redirecting problem still occurs.
<?php
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
if (empty($url)) {
  http_response_code(400);
  die('Error: URL parameter is missing.');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
  http_response_code(500);
  die('Error: Failed to fetch URL - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if (strpos($contentType, 'image/') === 0) {
  header("Content-Type: $contentType");
  echo $response;
} else {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML($response);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $elements = $xpath->query('//*[@src or @href]');
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    foreach (['src', 'href'] as $attribute) {
      $src = $element->getAttribute($attribute);
      if (!filter_var($src, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && !parse_url($src, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) {
        $element->setAttribute($attribute, $url . '/' . ltrim($src, '/'));
      }
    }
  }
  echo $doc->saveHTML();
}
?>

I've also noticed that it almost always needs a www. in the url or it may get a fatal error or won't work in general.

It works to some extent but breaks many times Then if you want help you could tell us what parameter you use when it works and also when it does not work

it will always use the ?url query in the url for the website it's going to proxy. https://server.com/?url=https://example.com.

Show us an ACTUAL example that WORKS! And then show us an ACTUAL example that DOES NOT WORK. We can then look at your code with some specific idea in mind. You could also tell us what you expect the results to be when you dont get the result you expect

It will work perfectly with https://example.com (real domain) and work very well on my friend's website https://bytepioneer.replit.app (one image can't load). Now for something such as https://google.com it loads only the basic things such as the search box and navigation bar. I expect it to load most images and the basic website structure.

Clearly the preg_replace_callback() is the only complicated thing in your code, and is therefore probably the thing that ruins everything. Try to explain to yourself what it does, and then debug it. For instance here's a simple page with a CSS include, which doesn't work. The same will happen with Javascript, which is what most pages depend upon. Also, using regular expressions to parse HTML is always a bad idea.

Well the regex does not work as you think. See https://regex101.com/r/7oMglQ/1 There is an href=" in there and it never gets found. I woudl try and be more helpful, but I am not good at regex's

"I'm very new to PHP" - and you decided to build a proxy as a first project? Sorry if that came off flippant, it is just kind of a big thing even for an advanced user (having had to build one a couple years ago), I mean no disrespect. You are missing support for redirects which is why https://google.com is behaving weird. You are only supporting images for pass-through, which is why the CSS and JS from your friend isn't loading. You are also parsing HTML as text using RegEx which is generally discouraged.

I changed the code a little bit and it works better but there is still a problem with redirects as the code does not like them. When the website redirects I want it to redirect to https://server.com/?url={redirected} but instead it directly redirects. Another thing that I noticed is that for such redirects that just redirect to a page (/page) it will redirect on my server going to https://server.com/page instead of https://server.com/?url=https://example.com/page.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); and probably a curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); would also be useful to stop you getting stuck somewhere

I don't think the filter and URL parsing are behaving how you expect them: https://3v4l.org/4KAoQ

I've added the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); however the same problem with redirects persists.
